# 7-Segment display control using Microprocessor

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, intel, microprocessors

MTS-88.C and I/O BOARD -08 has 8 (Eight) 7-segment displays and 20 key-pads on board. The displays are numbered from 7-SEG.1 to 7-SEG.8 and are connected to Port B’s PB7 to PB0 lines respectively. To display a character on a 7-segment display a byte has to be written to port B. The MSB 4 bits are the address of the 7-segment display and LSB 4 bits are the data. So **if we write 58 H to port B then the 6th 7-segment display will show data 8.**

I haven't understood one point. If we write 58H to port B, then how the **6th** 7 segment display is being selected? what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSB 4 bits are address of 7-segments displays. The first 7-segments display is selected for 0xH values (where x is the LSB 4bits value), the 2nd is selected for 1xH, and so on, with 5xH selecting the 6th display, since address are 0 based while names of displays start at 1.

Completed answer:

Since I don't have the manual for your card, I can just guess the routing and the circuits.

So I guess the 4 lines PB7 to PB4 are cabled on a [address decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_decoder) chip which will select the right 7-segment display, while the 4 lines PB3 to PB0 are cabled on a BCD-to-7segment converter ([Like this one for example](http://www.doctronics.co.uk/4511.htm)). Might be some other circuits involved, but this should be the base.
When you write xyH, you send xH to the address decoder and yH to the BCD converter, if you write 58h  you send 5h to the address decoder and 8h to the BCD converter.

Comment: I am very new to this topic. Can you please clarify a bit more on how The first 7-segments display is selected for 0xH values (where x is the LSB 4bits value), the 2nd is selected for 1xH, and so on? @Vincent G

Comment: I added some additional informations to my post, does it suffice?

Comment: Can you please help me in another question I have posted: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502350/reading-a-keypad-and-displaying-it-using-microprocessor)? @Vincent G

Comment: Nope, sorry, not very fluent with assembly.