# Reading a Keypad and displaying it using Microprocessor

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, x86-16, microprocessors

MTS-88.C and I/O BOARD -08 has 8 (Eight) 7-segment displays and 20 key-pads on board. The displays are numbered from 7-SEG.1 to 7-SEG.8 and are connected to Port B’s PB7 to PB0 lines respectively. To display a character on a 7-segment display a byte has to be written to port B. The MSB 4 bits are the address of the 7-segment display and LSB 4 bits are the data. So if we write 58 H to port B then the 6th 7-segment display will show data 8.

20 key-pads are numbered from P01 to P20 and are arranged in 5 columns and 4 rows. Rightmost column is connected to PB0 while leftmost column is connected to PB4. Topmost row is connected to PA0 while bottom-most row is connected to PA3. For detecting a key press, first a column must be activated by writing a byte to port B. Next, port A should be read. The valid values are 1, 2, 4 and 8 for row 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

[image: diagram]

**The experiment is to read the keypad and display the pressed key id on the specified 7-segment display**. In this experiment, I haven't understood some lines in the assembly code I have shown below. I have made comments beside those lines which I haven't understood.

```
MEMORY ADDRESS   ASSEMBLY CODE    
0000:0476        MOV AL,90
0000:0478        OUT 13,AL
0000:047A        MOV DL,00
0000:047C        MOV CX,0004H  //why storing 4 here
0000:047F        MOV AL,0F
0000:0481        MOV BL,CL
0000:0483        SHL BL,01  //why left shift for 4 times
0000:0485        SHL BL,01   
0000:0487        SHL BL,01
0000:0489        SHL BL,01
0000:048B        OR AL,BL  //why doing OR operation here
0000:048D        OUT 11,AL
0000:048F        IN AL,10
0000:0491        MOV BL,01
0000:0493        TEST AL,BL  //what is testing here
0000:0495        JE O4A7     //when we are jumping(what is the condition)
0000:0497        INC DL   // what are we storing in DL
0000:0499        CMP DL,09
0000:049C        JG  047A  //why are we comparing DL with 9
0000:049E        SHL BL,01
0000:04A0        TEST BL,10  //what is being tested here
0000:04A3        JE 0493
0000:04A5        LOOP O47F
0000:04A7        MOV AL,DL
0000:04A9        OUT 11,AL
0000:04AB        PUSH CX
0000:04AC        MOV CX,500
0000:04AF        NOP   //why is this operation needed
0000:04B0        LOOP 04AF
0000:04B2        POP CX
0000:04B3        JMP 047A
```

What is actually being done  with those lines I have marked above?

Comment: Please don't destroy question.

Answer (score 2):

I am puzzled how both the display and the keyboard uses port B. I **guess** there is some logic which detects the low 4 bits being `1` which would be invalid for a digit to display and then it switches into keyboard mode.

> TEST AL,BL  //what is testing here

It's testing through the 4 low bits of PA0-PA3 to see which one is set. This is the row number of the key pressed. Note that `BL` has been initialized to 1 at line `0491` and it is shifted left on line `049E` in a loop. So it goes through 1, 2, 4 and 8 as required.

> JE O4A7     //when we are jumping(what is the condition)

Apparently the keys use negative logic, that is you will get a 0 bit if a key is pressed. So the condition is looking for that 0 bit.

> NOP   //why is this operation needed

That's just part of a delay loop to make it longer.

> INC DL   // what are we storing in DL
>
> JG  047A  //why are we comparing DL with 9

I **think** the code only works for keys 0-9 because those can be represented by a single digit. So `DL` is the digit counter and the JG is for the end condition.

Update: given the new information, I can also say:

> MOV CX,0004H  //why storing 4 here

`CX` is the column counter, it is counting down from 4 to 0.

> //why left shift for 4 times

Since the diagram shows you need the column index in the top 4 bits, this does that.

> OR AL,BL  //why doing OR operation here

You need to output `4F`, `3F`, `2F`, `1F`, `0F` to port B. The top 4 bits are already set to the correct column index, what's left is to set the low 4 bits to `1`. Since `AL` has been loaded with `0F`, this achieves that.

The algorithm is as follows:

```c
start:
    key = 0;
    for(column = 4; column != 0; column--)
    {
        portB = (column << 4) | 0x0f;
        in = portA;
        for(row = 1; row != 0x10; row <<= 1)
        {
            if ((in & row) == 0)
            {
                portB = key;
                goto start;
            }
            if (++key == 10) goto start;
        }
    }
    goto start;
```

Comment: is DL counting how many times the key is pressed or checking which key is pressed? @Jester

Comment: It's counting which one.

Comment: will you please make a little more explanation about the line TEST AL,BL?
I mean when a key is being pressed what is happening in the row and column values and what are we checking through AL and BL? @Jester

Comment: `BL` has a single bit set that gets shifted repeatedly to the left. So that's testing `0001`, `0010`, `0100`, `1000` (in binary). See lines `0491` and `049E`. It tests the row values to find one that is zero. As for the column values, those should be similarly selected in a loop, except that part is not clear in the code (nor in the documentation).

Comment: For your clarification, you can view the image of the corresponding keypad [here](http://imgur.com/2sFexaL) @Jester

Comment: Ah, now **that** makes it clear. Since it shows to select row you must write `4F`, `3F`, `2F`, `1F`, `0F` to port B. That is what the initial part of the code does, in a convoluted way - it counts down `CX` from 4 to 0, moves that to the top 4 bits and inserts the 0F to the low 4 bits using `OR`.

Comment: Note that the diagram does not match the text description you have given, in particular this: _Rightmost column is connected to PB0 while leftmost column is connected to PB4._ But it does match the code at least :)

Comment: For detecting a key press, first a column must be activated by writing a byte to port B. Next, port A should be read. The valid values are 1, 2, 4 and 8 for row 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively. Where  the valid values are being checked? @Jester

Comment: Just told you 4 comments ago. 1,2,4 and 8 = `0001`, `0010`, `0100` and `1000`

Comment: ok. But how DL is getting the value I am pressing? Initially we are storing 00 in DL and at line 0497 we are increasing it. But but how it is knowing the key I am pressing? @Jester

Comment: `DL` is just counting the keys as they are checked for being pressed. So when the code detects a press, `DL` holds the number.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. what is being done using TEST BL,10  in the line 04A0? @Jester

Comment: That's 10 in hex, so 16 decimal, it is just the end condition for the row loop (1,2,4,8,16)

Comment: I forgot an important question. The MSB 4 bits are the address of the 7-segment display and LSB 4 bits are the data. So if we write 58 H to port B then the 6th 7-segment display will show data 8. If this is the logic, then, in the above assembly code which 7-segment display display (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) will show the pressed key? @Jester

Comment: The first one, since the top 4 bits are going to be zero.

Comment: yes. I also guessed that. But if I want to choose any of the display( say the 3rd one) where will I need to make the change mainly? @Jester

Comment: You will need to set the top 4 bits of `AL` to something else just before you write the value on line `04A9`.

Comment: If I press 6, how will I display it in the 3rd LED? I mean how will I set the top 4 bits without changing the others? @Jester

Comment: As it is now, it doesn't. Otherwise you can use `or al, 20` (in hex).

Comment: Can you specify a general rule of showing the pressed key to  in any LED ? I mean OR AL,X(in hex) what will be the value of x for all the LEDs from 1 to 8? @Jester

Comment: `00` to `70` obviously.

Comment: but  The valid values are 1, 2, 4 and 8 for row 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively. in line 0000:049E        SHL BL,01 , we are assigning values 1,2,4 and 8 repeatedly to bl, but how this is controlling the rows? Aren't we supposed to assign values to port A for selecting rows? @Jester

Comment: Your own post says: _first a column must be activated by writing a byte to port B. Next, port A should be read._ That is done at `048F`. The input value is then tested against the row bits.

Comment: when a column is first set, aren't we supposed to activate all the four rows one by one containing that column? where this has been done? @Jester

Comment: You don't activate the rows. You activate the columns and then check if any of those columns are connected to a row by a pressed button.

Comment: In line number 0000:04A3        JE 0493, why am I again testing it with TEST AL,BL? @Jester

Comment: Because `AL` has the data read from port `A` which shows if the current column is connected to a particular row by a pressed key. `BL` goes through testing all the rows.

Comment: Can you please give the complete algorithm of detecting the pressed key? I am getting  confused in the row section of the code. If you give the algorithm, it will help me a lot to understand the logic behind this clearly @Jester

Comment: can't you help me? @Jester

Comment: if ((in & row) == 0). can you give me an example of being this condition true according to the experiment? @Jester

Comment: It will be true if the key for the given row and column is pressed.